# how to prevent 2 'on' coming together in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

For the sentence,

> Sharp changes are provided later on, on the casting rather than on the pattern.

Is it grammatically correct to have 2 'on' together. What would be a better way to phrase the sentence.

Comment: That's grammatically correct and idiomatic. If you really dislike it, you could say 'at a later stage'.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine.  You may also consider this:

'Sharp changes are provided later on the casting rather than pattern.'

Orally, there would be a pause after 'later'.  Applying the concept of parallelism, we may omit the 2nd 'on the'.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence as written is gramatically correct. The comma serves to separate the two words.
It would be more elegant to write "Later on, sharp changes are provided on the casting rather than on the pattern".

Comment: -1 for that "more elegant" point. Learners might struggle with repeated prepositions in such contexts, but native speakers wouldn't normally even *notice*. And there's certainly no general principle that it's "better" to avoid the repetition.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, I have a doubt; if the first 'on' is removed, won't it make sense, like "Sharp changes are provided later, on the casting rather than on the pattern"?  I know it doesn't relate to OP's question, and still...?

Comment: @RamPillai: In the specified context, I'd say ***on*** is 100% redundant after ***later*** - as it would normally be with, say, ***further [on]***. Not that there's anything *wrong* with including redundant prepositions (native speakers do it all the time).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica; :)